# HTML5/Javascript Video Event Behaviour In Chrome 33.0.1750.154

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-video

I have a `video` element which I am dynamically controlling with `javascript`. It has been working great. Today I noticed something strange.

I have attached the following event listeners.

```
function registerListeners(listen) {
    listen.addEventListener('canplaythrough', canStartPlayback);
    listen.addEventListener('ended', onFinish);
    listen.addEventListener('loadeddata', onLoadComplete);
    listen.addEventListener('playing', onPlay);
    listen.addEventListener('error', mediaError);
}
```

And the code for `canStartPlayback` `onFinish` and `onPlay` is as follows.

```
function canStartPlayback() {
    if (!playing) {
        playing = true;
        $('.module-content-video-loader').stopSpin();
        $('.module-content-video-loader').hide();
        media.play();
    }
}

function onFinish() {
    if (playing) {
        playing = false;
        media.pause();
        media.currentTime = 0.0;
    }
}

function onPlay() {
    playing = true;
    if (!pending) {
        $('#skip').show();
    }
}
```

Now, I am currently finding that after `onFinish` has completed, I am immediately seeing `canStartPlayback` being fired again.

This is a description of the `canplaythrough` from Mozilla

`canplaythrough`    Sent when the ready state changes to CAN_PLAY_THROUGH, indicating that the entire media can be played without interruption, assuming the download rate remains at least at the current level. **Note: Manually setting the `currentTime` will eventually fire a `canplaythrough` event in firefox. Other browsers might not fire this event.**

I was under the impression, and have been seeing that `canplaythrough` is only fired once. Has chrome changed this recently and has anyone else found this to be occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `canplaythrough` event (like `canplay`) fires as the `readyState` property changes. These events and the property reflect how much video the browser is able to play from the **current position**. So if you seek to a new position that is not buffered, the browser can no longer play from your current position, so the `readyState` has to drop down to `HAVE_METADATA`. Once that new section is loaded, `readyState` eventually works its way back up to `HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA`, and the event will fire **again**.

As of [this fix](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=18975) from 2009, Chrome mimics the behavior of Firefox, which is to drop the `readyState` down to `HAVE_METADATA` on every seek, even if the video is fully buffered. Presumably, this is because even if the video is loaded from the network, it still takes time to load that section back into memory and display the current frame.

If you need to make sure your event only gets handled once, you can maintain more detailed state, or you can remove the listener after it runs the first time, like this:

```
media.removeEventListener('canplaythrough', canStartPlayback);
```

Here's an example that fires a bunch of these events and logs them to the console so you can see them in action when you seek:
http://jsbin.com/buparoye/1/edit